# Python: Using a returned value to reference another variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a program that calls a function, and the function returns an integer within a range of 1-25. I have a corresponding 25 lists in my program that, based on the value of this returned integer, I then need to pass to another function.

For example:

```
List1 = [1, 45]
...
List25 = [4, 584]

def ReturnListRef():
    a = 24
    return a
```

What would be the quickest way to use the returned value of '24' to send List24 to my next function?

Seems like it should be so easy to do, but after finishing up my beginners guide to Python book, I still can't achieve this without what seems like too many steps!

Comment: You know you can have a list of a list, too? `items = [[1, 45], [...], ..., [4, 584]]`.  With that you simply `return items[a]`

Comment: [Keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

Comment: `items = [[1, 45], [...], ..., [4, 584]]` then you can return `items[24]`

Comment: Aye, I simplified the above a little (lot). Each of the lists is pulled from a class and contains multiple lists.

Comment: You can have lists of lists of lists too. You can have any level of nesting you want, and the fact that the lists were pulled from a class (whatever you precisely meant by that, because it's not clear) won't interfere with sticking them in another list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dict to store your lists:

```
d = {24:[1, 45],25:[4, 584]}

def ReturnListRef():
    a = 24
    return a


def foo():
    var = d[ReturnListRef()]
    print var
print  foo()
[1, 45]
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I'm after.